# Site not redirecting on return confirm

Tags: javascript

So im trying to go to a specific url, but i want the user to confirm before hand.

This is what i have tried so far, it does give me the popup but it doesn't go to the url.

It does have to be within the PHP tag to work

```
<?php>
echo "
 <div class='menu-item' OnClick=\"return confirm(Are u sure');\" \"location.href='admin.php?drop='\">
";
?>
```

Comment: The PHP part of this code is not relevant; what the browser sees is the HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: You seem to have some quoting problems.

Comment: thats what i thought, just not sure how to fix em

Comment: You should be using `if(confirm(...) location.href='...';`

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't relevant here, it's HTML and JS. This should work

```js
function gotoUrl(){
        let text = 'Are u sure'

        if(confirm(text) == true){
            location.href = "admin.php?drop=";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class='menu-item' onclick="gotoUrl()">
    Go to URL
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank u very much, this seems to have worked for me.